# What is the use of """...""" in python instead of "..." or '...', especially in MySQLdb cursor.execute

Tags: python, sql, string, mysql-python

is there a difference if i use """..""" in the sql of cusror.execute. Even if there is any slight difference please tell

Comment: Maybe you should add an example? (edit your question)

Comment: Did you do anything to try to find the answer yourself? If so, what did you do? I ask because when I search on Google for "python triple quote", the answer is given in the very first result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's used to split the query over many lines to format it nicely:

```
db.query("""
    SELECT *
    FROM employee, department 
    WHERE employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID;
""")
```

Also using `"""..."""` around a string allows you to not escape `"` and `'` inside that string.

Answer (score 0):

No, other than the string can contain newlines.